# WPF Recursive call to Automation Peer API is not valid

Tags: wpf, exception, recursion, combobox, automation

I am receiving an error message

> "Recursive call to Automation Peer API is not valid"

- When loading a `datagrid` with a `datatemplatecolumn` containing a `combobox` column. The error ends up caught in our unhandled exception code. This seems to be an issue on my machine, and google has provided no source of guidance on resolving the issue. The issue appears to only occur when I am populating the `comboboxes` with data.
- Populating the comboboxes (if I do not load data) works correctly, and while the error is displayed I am able to see the data properly retrieved in the background.
- I am using a `WPF datagrid` where I'm using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` for adding a `combobox` inside the `grid`. I have the drop down list bound to an `enum` using an `objectdataprovider`.
- In the code behind when initializing my screen I use a `Linq2Sql` statement to retrieve data and populate the `Itemssource` of the grid.

```xml
    <grid:DataGrid.Resources>
     <ObjectDataProvider
      x:Key="ChangeTypeData"
      MethodName="GetValues"
      ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
      <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
       <x:Type TypeName="namespace:ChangeType" />
      </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
     </ObjectDataProvider>     
        </grid:DataGrid.Resources>
    
     <grid:DataGrid.Columns>
     <grid:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DatapointName}" Header="Datapoint Changed" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" />
     <grid:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Change Type">
      <grid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox
         Text="{Binding Path=ChangeTypeName}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ChangeTypeData}}"
         Name="dgcboChangeType"
    SelectionChanged="dgcboChangeType_SelectionChanged"/>
       </DataTemplate>
      </grid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</grid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
<grid:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Any and all guidance on solving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and the problem disappeared when I set the height of the DataGrid.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've bypassed the problem on my end by turning off Automation on the grid control.  I found that the problem was unique to the WPF Toolkit control, but I was having problems transitioning to the 4.0 official release DataGrid (unrelated to this question.)

So instead, I derive the class from the WPFToolkit and supply this override:

```
protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
{
   return null;
}
```

Maybe someone can tell us if this is a good idea or not.

Comment: I can confirm that this workaround helps. I noticed that it is important not to include the part "assembly=..." in the xml namespace declaration if the workaround class is located in the same assembly as the XAML file (i.e. the assembly= part is redundant anyway). If it is present, the compiler will complain about not finding the xml tag, although IntelliSense works.

Comment: I am getting the same problem but its not in the `DataGrid`, I have a `Combobox` inside a `Grid` and sometimes when i try to click on to select a different item from the list it breaks and throws the same exception so i guess its a` combobox` problem, has anyone got any other solution.

Comment: Sorry it's a year late @FaisalMalikyar, but I just hit this for a ComboBox as well. Solution appears to be the same - subclass the existing ComboBox, e.g. *public class ComboBox : System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox*, add code as above to new class, then add reference to your class in the XAML code, i.e. replacing the existing ComboBox with your own.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same error. However for me it was strange that the same application was working fine on my laptop and caused the error on my desktop PC. The same OS, the same architecture and the same Visual Studio with the same add-ons.

So I checked references to WPFToolkit on my laptop, where everything was fine. It pointed to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WPF Toolkit\v3.5.40619.1\WPFToolkit.dll
```

then I checked reference on my desktop, it pointed to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WPF Toolkit\v3.5.50211.1\WPFToolkit.dll
```

As you can see I had **two different versions of WPFToolkit installed**. I copied whole folder from my laptop to my desktop, changed references from version v3.5.50211.1 to v3.5.40619.1 and the problem was resolved. No more exceptions. Hope this will help someone as well.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same problem in NET 3.5 with WPFToolkit DataGrid.

I have bound my WPFToolkit DataGrid to EntityFramework ObservableCollection, with hierarchy of entities that have two way associations (Parent<->Items).

I solved the issue by disabling implicitly enabled AutoGenerateColumns on the DataGrid, and manually setting the columns.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the same problem - are you using the datagrid from the WPFToolkit, or the one that ships with .NET 4.0.  We're still using the toolkit one here.

Also, I've notice that this problem does not occur when using the app through remote desktop.

Similar problem posted here:

http://wpf.codeplex.com/workitem/14443

With a proposed solution.  Haven't had a chance to try it.

Comment: I am using the WPFToolkit Datagrid.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. So I checked also the reference to the WPFToolkit. I had two same versions of WPFToolkit installed (Version v3.5.50211.1), but only on my Laptop works it fine.

So I put the older version **v3.5.40619.1** on my Windows Embedded Standard 7 PC and no more exceptions.

So I came to the conclusion that in some cases the newer Version has some problems with the runing system.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I also had same problem when I am running Microsoft Test Manager with our WPF application. We were using the WPFtoolkit version v3.5.50211.1, replacing WPF toolkit with lower version v3.5.40619.1 has solved this problem.

Now we are able to run the MTM tool and WPF application both simultaneously.

In WPFToolkit v3.5.50211.1 one bug is fixed related to UI Automation and I guess because of that this automation peer issue is coming while using the latest WPFtoolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by replacing both the DataGrid and the ComboBox in the WPF XAML file with the following two derived classes which both override the OnCreateAutomationPeer() method.

```
public class SafeDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class SafeComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem crop up on an older solution (although it was working fine on my local dev computer, but failing on the test system (with WPFToolkit 3.5.50211.1)

Turned out my local dev computer had an older WPFToolkit: 3.5.40128.1

However I did a little more checking around and realised that the problem was only when the DataGrid was a Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid (ie a WPFToolkit one), and it contained a control from the System.Windows.Controls namespace (in this case a ComboBox) - and from the .Net PresentationFramework.dll )

We'd updated the solution to .Net 4.7.1 from .Net 4.5.1 -> which would have meant a new version of the PresentationFramework.dll, but the WPFToolkit dll had not changed.

Decided that the best way to fix this was to just remove the WPFToolkit.dll reference, and update all the DataGrids from Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid to the newer System.Windows.Controls.Datagrid.