# Override protected virtual without inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a bunch of DataGrids in my app. I need to override some protected virtual method for all of them. Is there something better than using derived from DataGrid class with not so familiar name? I would like solution like attached property to be able to specify overidden behaviour with custom property.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Could you please rephrase the question?

Comment: What's wrong with inheritance in this case? Is the problem that you cannot call your derived class DataGrid, but must choose another name? If yes, think about how strange it'd be to have a proliferation of identically named classes all doing things differently.

Comment: What I want to do is to fix WPFToolkit DataGrid strange bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017786/wpf-recursive-call-to-automation-peer-api-is-not-valid I.e. override OnCreateAutomationPeer(). But I don't want make changes all over the app code. I don't think it means the DataGrid will do different. I just trying to get rid of weird exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override. Override the method in your own MyOwnDataGrid (or a shorter name). Then use that class whereever you use datagrid. If you have hundreds of grids you must have an odd application design. If you do not want to change each location where you create a `new DataGrid()` I believe you can change the using directives.

```
using DatGrid = My.NameSpace.MyOwnDataGrid;
```

You still have to do that for each file using datagrids, and it makes the code a bit confusing to read so I think it is better to just do a global search/replace of "new DataGrid(" to "new MyOwnDataGrid(" and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, but all my DataGrid defined in XAML, not by new.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you cannot override a method without inheriting from that method. [MSDN-Override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). 
The only way to override a method is to inherit from that base class. Is there a reason why you do not want to inherit from the base class?