# Root Cause: Recursive call to Automation Peer API is not valid

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

We've used WPF Tookit DataGrid and .NET 3.5 for about 2 years. And we've got two cases which throw exception - "Recursive call to Automation Peer API is not valid". **It's quit strange and eratic, very few PCs has such issue.**

**Case One:**

A dropdown combox (WPF Tookit DataGrid as DropDown content control):

And it can be resolved by:

```
protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
{
   return null;
}
```

This solution is from [WPF Recursive call to Automation Peer API is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017786/wpf-recursive-call-to-automation-peer-api-is-not-valid).

**Case Two:**

A WPF Tookit DataGrid has a Temlate Column , which the cell template has a dropdown combox (WPF Tookit DataGrid as DropDown content control). It can not be fixed by the solution above.

```
*Exception Stack:
Exception object: 0ac4e048
Exception type:   System.InvalidOperationException
Message:          Recursive call to Automation Peer API is not valid.
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    0036E3A4 61A0CEFE PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.GetChildren()+0x366bde
    0036E3D4 616A5C34 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x18
    0036E3EC 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E404 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E41C 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E434 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E44C 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E464 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E47C 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E494 616A5E52 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.ValidateConnected(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0xaa
    0036E4A8 616A444E PresentationCore_ni!MS.Internal.Automation.ElementProxy.StaticWrap(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer, System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x1a
    0036E4C0 616A7C69 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateChildrenInternal(Int32)+0x341
    0036E52C 616A791A PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateChildren()+0xa
    0036E530 11EDC66E UNKNOWN!Microsoft.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridItemAutomationPeer.GetChildrenCore()+0x1e
    0036E540 616A662B PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.EnsureChildren()+0x23
    0036E558 616A634C PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.GetChildren()+0x2c
    0036E588 616A5C34 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x18
    0036E5A0 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E5B8 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E5D0 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E5E8 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E600 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E618 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E630 616A5C73 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.isDescendantOf(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x57
    0036E648 616A5E52 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.ValidateConnected(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0xaa
    0036E65C 616A444E PresentationCore_ni!MS.Internal.Automation.ElementProxy.StaticWrap(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer, System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x1a
    0036E674 616A6F3E PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.ProviderFromPeer(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer)+0x1e
    0036E680 619DBBD1 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.RaiseAutomationEvent(System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationEvents)+0x7ab6d5
    0036E690 609783AA PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.SelectorAutomationPeer.RaiseSelectionEvents(System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)+0x22
    0036E6B0 60C48560 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.OnSelectionChanged(System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)+0xbef278
    0036E6C4 124C17E7 UNKNOWN!UNKNOWN+0x17
    0036E6EC 60061113 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Object>, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Object>)+0x4f
    0036E704 6005FE17 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector+SelectionChanger.End()+0xdf
    0036E738 6005E325 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector+SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(System.Object, Boolean)+0x11d
    0036E76C 60060D02 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectedItemChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)+0xb2
    0036E798 627585EC WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x4c
    0036E7C4 60073E40 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)+0x50
    0036E8F4 627583BC WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x3c
    0036E94C 6275676B WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x71b
    0036EA0C 627594CD WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0xad
    0036EA34 600AD85A PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean)+0x62
    0036EA4C 600AD31D PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(System.Object, Boolean)+0x1fd
    0036EAA0 600AA9D8 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(System.Object)+0x194
    0036EACC 60097C49 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt)+0x38d
    0036EB74 600C3D51 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean)+0x19
    0036EB80 600C3D19 PresentationFramework_ni!MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine+Task.Run(Boolean)+0x31
    0036EB94 600C3C36 PresentationFramework_ni!MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(System.Object)+0xb6
    0036EBB0 600C2CBA PresentationFramework_ni!MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(System.Object, System.EventArgs)+0x1e
    0036EBC0 61271CD8 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()+0x154
    0036EBF8 6127159E PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()+0x926
    0036ECF8 61277F4D PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(System.Object)+0x19
    0036ECFC 61277F28 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext+InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()+0x10
    0036ED00 61277EC2 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()+0x76
    0036ED1C 6127785A PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object)+0x8a
    0036ED68 612777AA PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(System.Object)+0x6e
    0036ED80 6274FE83 WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x53
    0036EDA0 6274FE0C WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x9c
    0036EDE8 62752C95 WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x8d
    0036EE24 62752BF8 WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x38
    0036EE2C 642F4D85 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)+0x51
    0036F2D0 642F4C8A mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x6a
    0036F2E8 642F7F92 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+0x7e
    0036F30C 642F7F04 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x2c
    0036F328 62752B28 WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x68
    0036F364 6274E7FE WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x15e
    0036F3A8 6274E9D7 WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x63
    0036F3F8 627500A6 WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0xbe
    0036F444 6274FFD5 WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x7d
    0036F454 6274FE83 WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x53
    0036F474 6274FDB2 WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x42
    0036F4BC 6274E2CC WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0xb4
    0036F504 6274F8B8 WindowsBase_ni!Unknown+0x104*
```

Many threads just has a walkaround solution about the issue, Does any one know have any idea about the **Root Cause** of Recursive call to Automation Peer API is not valid?

Comment: I dont know but it's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old thread but i just had the exact same issue after reloading a project i completed some months back.

The only real change of significance was that i had installed RoboForm to trial and it had expired.

I could re-create very easily and consistently, Uninstalled it and problem is now gone.